# White photos on Canon S5 IS

Tags: canon, exposure, white-balance, overexposure

I have an old CANON S5 IS camera, which I was using for half a year until it started to take completely white photos.

Exposure and white balance are set to normal. ISO is also set to auto.

In low-light or while filming everything is normal, but outside photos are just plain white.

I have added a photo below for reference and EXIF (but it is completely white). Can anyone help?

[image: White photo for reference]

Comment: unfortunately, imgur strips all exif data at upload. You'll have to post it somewhere else if the exif data is required, & link back from here

Comment: In which mode you take photos? Maybe its on M, try on P, or Auto

Comment: What ISO, aperture, and shutter duration are listed in the EXIF info? Where did you set the mode dial?