# My photos are fully white, how can I recover the image?

Tags: canon

All photos I took while travelling faced the same issue: they are fully white.

Why is that? And can I recover an image from this photo?

I have included a sample below.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE. Can you please [edit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/122478/edit) your question to describe what issue you exactly face, how you took the photo (which settings, which scene) and perhaps an upload of the photo itself? Now you have uploaded a screenshot of your computer, which does not clarify what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited the question for you, and included the sample image (you posted a screenshot of that link). However, I cannot know what settings you used. Can you upload your photo [here](https://exifinfo.org/), and include the resulting address in your question?

Comment: Relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/116637/9161, but question asker there never provided details, so no answer could be given.

Comment: There is literally nothing here to recover. Here's a very forced attempt to extract any additional information… https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYI7F.jpg What's left to concentrate on is why it went wrong. Was this a digital or film image? What's the camera, what were the settings? If film, have you looked at the negative? If digital can you upload the original somewhere other than here (google, dropbox etc) so we can see the exif data?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I think that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Besides having no content, your reference image is 3 MB. I'm guessing you cropped or resized this from a larger original?  As Saaru Lindestøkke suggested, upload the **Original** to https://exifinfo.org/ and report the **EXIF** results.

Comment: @inkista It could be an answer, but it also may be commentary on the contents of the uploaded image, which seems to be a screenshot of the image being displayed on a monitor, rather than the image itself. There may (doubtfully, but one never knows) be more information in the actual image if the screen was adjusted too brightly.

Comment: @inkista - indeed, it was more a request for further clarification, The simple explanation of massive over-exposure falls down because the date-stamp survived. I can't think that it could be film because of that (which took me until after that comment to realise), so the only conclusion I can arrive at is that it was digital, allowing the stamp to be overlaid on any previous exposure. The exif data may clarify that.

Comment: Ach… a final "D'oh!" moment. It 100% has to be digital, the date-stamp is orange with a black stroke. Try doing that on film!

Answer (score 5):

For this answer, I assume that you are using a digital camera.

The image is overexposed. Without knowing your setup, we can only give general advice.

- Your camera might be set to M (manual mode). Switch to A, P, or some other automatic mode.
- You might have set an exposure correction.
- The ISO setting might be too high for sunny outdoor shooting.
- On some cameras, you must set the aperture ring to the highest value (e.g. 32) for the camera to be able to control the aperture. Some lenses have a switch to lock it into this position.

There is not much left to recover, most of the picture is white, with some faint shadows in the lower left corner. I've reduced brightness and increased contrast:

[image: edited image]

You might have more luck with your other pictures. If your camera was set to store RAW data, you might get better results using these.

Comment: What do you mean by "you must set the aperture ring to the highest value"?

Comment: @osullic e.g. see https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75378/will-nikon-d-lenses-work-on-a-nikon-d810-camera/75380#75380 - my Nikon just overexposes if it can't control the aperture.