# Any fix for overexposed shot JPEG Canon Rebel T3i

Tags: canon, exposure

I recently was on a trip with a loaner Canon Rebel T3i and although I intended to use landscape settings, wearing it around my neck I think it may have jostled it into manual mode. I've been reading the manual and playing with photo editing tools (lightroom, corel) and so far have not found any way to fix the images, which appear just as blank white captures. The camera default uses JPEG image format so I do not have the raw files. I understand it may not be possible but wondering if there is any fix out there, these were one of a kind photos of a trip to Peru and I'm willing to pay for nice software if something else out there can rectify this kind of thing.

Comment: Related: [Why are blown highlights particularly bad in digital photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13427/15871) and [Why is my long exposure shot all white?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80031/15871) and [My photos are fully white, how can I recover the image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/122478/15871)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Lightroom or Corel can't recover any detail then no other program is going to either.

In a jpeg white is recorded as RGB 255/255/255, so if every pixel has exactly the same numbers/values then there is no way to differentiate them (discern detail).